# Java servlet is not affected by code change

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I made a hello world servlet that works fine

```
@WebServlet("/HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print("<html><body>");
    out.print("<h3>Hello World</h3>");
    out.print("</body></html>");
}
```

}

When i run it on server (Apache Tocmat 8.0 at localhost) i get the desired response (An html page display "Hello World").

Here's what's weird. After i make a change in the code

```
    out.print("<html><body>");
    out.print("<h3>Not a hello world servlet anymore!</h3>");
    out.print("</body></html>");
```

and I save and run on server again (restarting the server), i dont get the modified html page and still get the old one ("Hello World" page).

This problem is solved by closing eclipse and starting it again. After that, when i run on server my servlet, I get the desired response ("Not a hello world servlet anymore!").

How can i make it so i don't have to restart eclipse for my changes to take effect?

Comment: Do you clean server before restarting? It could cache your information, that's one of the possible's reasons

Comment: @m.aibin I have cleaned the server and the problem still persists

Comment: Look at the duplicate question above.

Comment: @austinwernli i did and my problem isn't solved by checking the project->Build Automatically (it was already checked)

Comment: Are you using an IDE?

Comment: @fnocetti yes Eclipse IDE - J2EE and JDK 1.8

Answer (score 0):

When Eclipse builds your project, does it overwrite or move the .class files into the WEB-INF/classes directory of your webserver?
This would be necessary for the code change to be effected on the running WebApp instance